# ASP.NET Core WebAPI: Unsupported Media Type - HTTP 415

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I try to create an new department, but I get this error:

```
{
    "type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title":"Unsupported Media Type",
    "status":415,
    "traceId":"|3361f693-4c3294040da78eae."
}
```

Could anyone tell me why this error occurs? I could also not do other crud operation to department.

Here this is my department controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebAPI.Models;

namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DepartmentsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly EmployeeDbContext _context;

        public DepartmentsController(EmployeeDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Departments
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? pageNumber)
        {
            ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;
            ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
     
            if (searchString != null)
            {
                pageNumber = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

            var departments = from d in _context.Departments
                              select d;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                departments = departments.Where(d => d.departmentName.Contains(searchString)
                               || d.departmentName.Contains(searchString));
            }

            int pageSize = 3;

            return View(await PaginatedList<Department>.CreateAsync(departments.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
        }

        // GET: Departments/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var department = await _context.Departments
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

            if (department == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(department);
        }

        // GET: Departments/Create
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("departmentName")] Department department)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _context.Add(department);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                    "Try again, and if the problem persists " +
                    "see your system administrator.");
            }

            return View(department);
        }

        // GET: Departments/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var department = await _context.Departments.FindAsync(id);

            if (department == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(department);
        }

        // POST: Departments/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,departmentName")] Department department)
        {
            if (id != department.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(department);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!DepartmentExists(department.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(department);
        }

        // GET: Departments/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var department = await _context.Departments
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

            if (department == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(department);
        }

        // POST: Departments/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var department = await _context.Departments.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Departments.Remove(department);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool DepartmentExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Departments.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `Department` model class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI.Models
{
    public class Department
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Department Name")]
        [Display(Name = "Department Name")]
        public String departmentName { get; set; }

        // Navigation Properties
        public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

create view

```
@Sergey `@model WebAPI.Models.Department

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Department</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" >
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="departmentName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="departmentName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="departmentName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary ">Back to List</a>
    @* <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>*@
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        // Add the following code if you want the name of the file appear on select
        $(".custom-file-input").on("change", function () {
            var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
            $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
        });
    </script>
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
`
```

Comment: How you are **calling** your API methods?? "Unsupported media" often occurs if your make a `POST` request to an URI, and you forget to set the proper `Content-Type` HTTP header for that request (should be e.g. `application/json` or whatever your content type is, in your concrete case)

Comment: http://localhost:5000/api/Departments/Create  POST method

Comment: OK  that's the URL - but what's the **code** that calls this URL?? What HTTP headers are you setting??

Comment: Hi @hanushi, could you please share how do you post the data? By using postman or any others? Also share the data you post.

Comment: i was wrong, i used MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework. so i can view using dot net core. And i don't know how can i call API methods

Comment: Can you post create view too, pls?

Comment: @Sergey i post create view

Comment: Hi @hanushi, if you use asp.net core mvc, please remove `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")] [ApiController] ` and be sure the razor view named `Create.cshtml` and located in `Views/Departments` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  [ApiController] and fix the controller actions:

```
       [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            var model=new Department();
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create( Department department)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _context.Add(department);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                    "Try again, and if the problem persists " +
                    "see your system administrator.");
            }

            return View(department);
        }
```

and view

```
<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller"Departments" "method="post" >
 <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
  <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" value="@Model.Id" />
            .....
        </form>
```